# Google Maps refreshing everytime mouse is clicked

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

http://task4adamholt.appspot.com/?guestbook_name=Cars

For some reason every time the mouse is clicked, whether it be on the table or the actual map itself it refreshes all the maps for some reason.

Does anyone have any idea why, it's really strange. The .js file includes the following function

```
function getLoc(lon,lat,id) {
    function initialize() {
        var mapProp = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon),
            zoom: 12,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(id), mapProp);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon),
            map: map,
            title: 'Sent Here!'
        });
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'click', initialize);
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the line that's causing the problem.

```
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'click', initialize);
```

It listens for a click on the window, and runs the functions whenever a click happens, refreshing the map. I would definitely change the 'click' event to something else, like DOM ready.

Comment: Thank you very much, it completely skipped my mind that was still there!